# How to get Pandoc from m Pandoc?

Tags: haskell, pandoc

I started to write few programs using the pandoc api ,taking examples  from , https://johnmacfarlane.net/BayHac2014/#/the-pandoc-types , But I am unable to isolate Pandoc from m Pandoc.

```
module ImageAttr where
import Text.Pandoc.Builder
import Text.Pandoc.Generic
import Text.Pandoc.Definition
import Text.Pandoc.JSON
import qualified Data.Char as DataChar
import qualified Data.List as DataList
import Data.Either
import Text.Parsec as Parsec
import Text.Pandoc
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Text.IO as TIO

fromRight :: b -> Either a b -> b
fromRight _ (Right b) = b
fromRight b _         = b


fromLeft :: b -> Either b a -> b
fromLeft  _ (Left b)  = b
fromLeft  b _        = b


main :: IO ()
main = do
        result <- runIO $ do
            doc <- readMarkdown def (T.pack "[testing](url)")
            writeRST def doc
        x<-((handleError result))
        print x
```

output is String but I need pandoc ast previously it was Either PandocError Pandoc type , instead I am getting "m Pandoc". How to get Pandoc out of "m Pandoc".

any Thought?
By the way , I am new and still learning haskell.

I am getting error message  as :

```
ImageSizeModifer.hs:28:12:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘PandocIO a0’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: print ""
    In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
      ‘do { doc <- readMarkdown def (T.pack "[testing](url)");
            print "" }’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
Prelude T>
```

My problem is I need Pandoc , but I have not much idea how to to get it ? There are new PandocIO and PandocPure , I believe these are new.

Comment: See [`runIO :: PandocIO a -> IO (Either PandocError a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.0.4/docs/Text-Pandoc-Class.html#v:runIO).

Comment: Alec , I tried Prelude T Text.Pandoc> let  doc = readMarkdown def (T.pack "[testing](url)")
Prelude T Text.Pandoc> :t doc
doc :: PandocMonad m => m Pandoc , is it possible to get Pandoc out of m Pandoc

Comment: @amali I just gave you the answer in my previous comment. :). `doc <- runIO (readMarkdown def (T.pack "[testing](url)")`. You should have `doc ::  Either PandocError Pandoc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new version of `pandoc` has [`readMarkdown :: PandocMonad m => ReaderOptions -> Text -> m Pandoc`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.0.4/docs/Text-Pandoc-Readers.html#v:readMarkdown). This follows the usual `mtl`-style of specifying the constraints on the monad, instead of the actual monad.

That means that to use `readMarkdown`, you need to pick a particular `m` satisfying `PandocMonad`. You can find what instances `PandocMonad` has by scrolling to the "Instances" section of [its doc](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.0.4/docs/Text-Pandoc-Class.html#t:PandocMonad). In this case, you find:

- `PandocMonad PandocPure` maybe interesting
- `PandocMonad PandocIO` maybe interesting
- `(MonadTrans t, PandocMonad m, Functor (t m), MonadError PandocError (t m), Monad (t m), Applicative (t m)) => PandocMonad (t m)` - not interesting, requires another `PandocMonad m`
- `PandocMonad m => PandocMonad (ParsecT s st m)` - not interesting, requires another `PandocMonad m`

Now, scrolling past where `PandocPure` and `PandocIO` are defined, you can find ways of running extracting information out of those:

- [`runIO :: PandocIO a -> IO (Either PandocError a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.0.4/docs/Text-Pandoc-Class.html#v:runIO)
- [`runPure :: PandocPure a -> Either PandocError a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-2.0.4/docs/Text-Pandoc-Class.html#v:runPure)

Combining either of these functions with `readMarkdown`, you can get a concrete `Either` type.

```
runIO (readMarkdown def (T.pack "[testing](url)")) :: IO (Either PandocError Pandoc)
runPure (readMarkdown def (T.pack "[testing](url)")) :: Either PandocError Pandoc
```

Note that I know nothing about Pandoc or its API - all I did was walk through the above process.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at http://pandoc.org/using-the-pandoc-api.html for a basic tutorial on using the pandoc 2.x API.

Comment: Hi john, is it possible to pass argument to filters dynamically ?